# Why does "(seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280 / 233280.0" generate a random number?

Tags: random

```js
// Found this seed-based random generator somewhere
// Based on The Central Randomizer 1.3 (C) 1997 by Paul Houle (houle@msc.cornell.edu)

var seed = 1;

/**
 * return a random number based on a seed
 * @param seed
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getNextValue() {
    seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
    return seed/(233280.0);
}

function setSeed(_seed_) {
    seed = _seed_;
}

module.exports = {
    nextValue: getNextValue,
    seed: setSeed
};
```

See https://github.com/dylang/shortid/blob/master/lib/random/random-from-seed.js

Comment: It's not really random, it's pseudo-random based of a provided seed. Resetting the seed gives consistent output. As the comment says, it is based on [The Central Randomizer](http://www.honeylocust.com/javascript/randomizer.html). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yeah, I see them are not really random. I'm curious about those magic numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `(seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280 / 233280.0` generate a random number?

**It doesn't.** It generates a completely deterministic number. The resulting sequence **may look random** at first glance, hence this is a pseudo-random generator. More precisely, it's a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

You stated you are curious about the "magic" numbers. Well, they are really mostly arbitrarily-chosen from a practically infinite set of numbers. Often, prime coefficients are used (especially as the divisor) for number theoretic reasons (primarily in order to avoid very obvious repetitions in the generated pattern); however, naive LCGs like this produce very low quality PRNs, so if there's a serious need for good-quality pseudo-randomness, it's quite pointless to try and tune a LCG – just use a better PRNG algorithm.

Comment: I was with you until you said "arbitrarily chosen".  There are actually some pretty stringent requirements to achieve maximal cycle length and bring the number of hyperplanes k-tuples fall on close to or at [Marsaglia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Marsaglia) theoretical upper bound.

Comment: @pjs still the implementor has lots of degrees of freedom. It's "arbitrary" only in that sense. Of course there are requirements; if you continue reading my answer, you can see I enumerate some of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a random number generator, but a pseudo-random number based of a provided seed. Resetting the seed will reset `getNextValue` and give consistent output.

As the comment mentions, this code is based on the [The Central Randomizer](http://www.honeylocust.com/javascript/randomizer.html). Apparently this code was created because `Math.random` did not work in the now-archaic Netscape 2. In turn, this implementation is based on existing pseudo-random number generators. See [Original source of `(seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280` random algorithm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/260969/120031) for more information on the origins of this algorithm.

Technically `Math.random` is also pseudo-random, but you do not have control over the seed, so this code does have a potentially useful property. If you give it a consistent seed, you will get consistent output across reloads.